# Does String.prefix() work like String.suffix if using a right-to-left language?

Tags: swift, string, prefix, suffix

Does String.prefix() work like String.suffix() if using a right-to-left language? That is instead of returning the left side of the string it returns the right side.

Comment: `prefix()` returns the initial characters, no matter how they are layed out or displayed. Did you try it yourself? Do you have a concrete example where the result is not as you would expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, their functionality doesn't change. Right-to-left only matters when you're displaying any text to the user, for example in a `UITextField`. The `String`s you access in your code are independent of the writing direction.

Answer (score 0):

Considering how a String is essentially an array of characters, a String object does not "know" that it is in any given language. Strings methods will always go "right-to-left" (so to speak).

So, no matter what the language is, `String.prefix()` will always return the initial characters (going right to left), and `String.suffix()` will always return the final characters (going right to left).

UPDATE:

The sequence of words only matters when displaying text to the user.